# phpMyAdmin: change default number of rows displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

By default, phpMyAdmin shows me 30 rows whenever I load a table (the query contains "LIMIT 30"). I generally want to see (up to) a few hundred rows.

Is there a way to change that default setting?

Comment: Thanks everybody! That had been bugging me for a while. :)

Comment: **Update** - Please scroll down to Rick's answer and see if you can confirm it; it sounds like the new correct answer to me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your phpMyAdmin directory, there will be a file called "config.inc.php".

Find the line where it sets the MaxRows value:

```
$cfg['MaxRows'] = 1000;
```

And change the value to whatever you want.

Comment: In my copy, that line didn't exist, so I added it.

Comment: a helpful setting in that regard is $cfg['RepeatCells'] = 50, which defines when the header / columnnames should be repeated. Here: every 50 lines.

Comment: In newer versions of phpMyAdmin you can change this setting directly by going to Preferences > Main Frame > Browse Mode > Maximum number of rows to display.

Comment: There's an option to save it to a configuration file you can later reload, or just save it to your browser's local storage (for more modern browsers). If you go the browser storage route, it'll prompt you when you open PMA in a new session about loading it.

Comment: Another point that tripped me up.  I am managing multiple servers through phpmyadmin, so I kept adding this configuration into config.inc.php like this: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['MaxRows'] = 100;  This will NOT work!  This setting is site-wide and not server-specific. Just put it into config.inc.php as shown above.

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04LTS using apt installed phpmyadmin config.inc.php is pulled from /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, not the root of the phpmyadmin install as stated in Documentation.html

Comment: @fn27 What do you mean, it's temporary? I just tried it, reloaded page, tried with a different browser, but the setting stayed.

Answer (score 41):

Using phpMyAdmin version 3.4 and above you are able to change the default rows shown by:

On the phpMyAdmin home screen click `Settings` >> `Main frame` >> `Browse mode` and altering the value within `Maximum number of rows to display`.

Comment: +1! Thanks for bringing an updated answer to an old question! I'm no longer using phpAdmin, so I can't confirm this, but if it's correct, it should be the accepted answer. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: It works. This is better answer, if you don't have access to phpmyadmin config file.

Comment: Works great and it is per user, so every user can set it the way he wants.

Comment: Looks like in 4.x now it's `Home` > `More Settings` > `Main Panel` > `Browse Mode`.

Comment: Tobias J is correct. I'm glad the option is there, less glad that the limit is 25 by default now. There really is no risk of "hanging the server" from fetching 500 rows in 99.99% of what PHPMyAdmin is used for.

Answer (score 12):

I have no access to `config.inc.php`

To show more records I add to my query:

`LIMIT 0,1000;`

to show 1,000 records, from 0 to 1000.

You can change 1000 to any number according to your needs.

One example:

```
SELECT id, folio, sucursal
FROM equipos
WHERE sucursal = 3
ORDER BY folio
LIMIT 0,1000;
```

Greetings from Mexico!

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to change the limits on the query, it asks how to change the default setting.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon Be that as it may, this is a fantastically useful answer for running one off heavy queries that return more than the default number of rows. Otherwise you have to update the default or run the query twice, the first time to get access to the show all button!

Comment: This was extremely helpful to me.  I work on a lot of shared hosting sites and on projects where multiple remote multiple people all using the same phpmyadmin.  Thanks for posting

Answer (score 3):

There is a config setting for this:

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxRows

Answer (score 3):

Already Checked.....
Simple Steps Follow:-

1. Go PhpAdmin
2. Select Your Table
3. In Your table there is a field name Show, Which is actually a Button. Here two boxes present like(Start row(0)  Number of Rows(1000) Header every(100)).
                                               ----
4. Press on Show button.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the installation files, you should use Ricks answer with "click `Settings` >> `Main frame` >> `Browse mode` and altering the value within `Maximum number of rows to display`", but it can be that this does not take effect for other users. If so, you can:

---

- login as root
- choose database `phpmyadmin`
- select table `pma_userconfig`
- search for the user in question (field `username`)
- edit the field `config_data` by adding e.g. `"MaxRows":1000` to the contents in brackets, e.g. results in `{"MaxRows":1000,"lang":"de"}`

---

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the file config.inc.php in your phpmyadmin directory
2. Edit it in any text editor
3. look for the line which contains the word `$cfg['MaxRows']`
4. if it has value like this (`$cfg['MaxRows'] = 30;` ) just edit the number (30) to the number of rows you like 
   -- if that line doesn't exist just Add it at the end of the file before the `?>` tag as follow:

[image: As shown in the picture]

```
......

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en';
$cfg['MySQLManualType'] = 'searchable';

$cfg['MaxRows'] = 1000;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin has a config file called config.inc.php. You should be able to find appropriate setting in there.

Comment: I have a cheapo cpanel web hosting account and can't see config.inc.php anywhere - do I need to create it and if so, where?

Comment: @cskillbeck I have cpanel as well. For me this is at /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/

Answer (score 0):

just add the line :
$cfg['MaxRows'] = 300;
to 
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php (ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The answers that refer to updating the MaxRows value in config.inc.php are correct, however, they fail to mention that this setting may be missing from config.inc.php.

The more complete procedure is as follows:

1. Find the file config.inc.php in your phpMyAdmin directory and open this in an editor
2. Look for the line that starts with $cfg['MaxRows']
3. If it is commented out, remove the '//' in front of the $cfg...
4. If the line is not present (it is missing in the default installation) then go to the bottom of the document and add the row

   $cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;
5. You can set the value for the 'MaxRows' attribute can be set to any one of the following: 25, 50, 100, 250, 500
6. Save the document and restart

Notice that there is a file called config.sample.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin directory. If you open this, you will see a list of possible settings (and some explanations) that you can add to your config.inc.php file to further configure phpMyAdmin.

I hope that this helps.