# Getting rid of the "limit 0, 30" that phpmyadmin tacks onto the end of SQL tests

Tags: phpmyadmin, performance-testing

I'm running some SQL statements against a large database to test their execution speed. Right now, all database management is through phpmyadmin. With our hosting provider, it would be a proper pain to set up another kind of DB access. And phpadmin is rewriting the queries, invalidating the tests.

Specifically, when I ask phpmyadmin to run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE target = 35
```

...phpmyadmin transforms this into...

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE target = 35 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

...and of course THAT runs plenty fast. That's not what I'm testing. I'm testing how long it takes to pull all million records.

Is there a way to get phpmyadmin to run the actual query I put in, without modification?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413288/phpmyadmin-change-default-number-of-rows-displayed

Comment: Nice. I have to say I'm still hoping for a general purpose "run the sql statement I asked for without changes" method. Actually asking phpmyadmin to display a million rows on the browser would bring its own set of problems.

Comment: You'd probably be better off writing a small PHP script for testing the time it takes to pull a million records if that's all you want to do.

Comment: Actually, I just tried `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0 , 1000000` and it overrides the 30 limit anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration directive makes a "Show all" button appear, on a results page:
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=showall#cfg_ShowAll

This "Show all" button permits you to see all results, without a LIMIT clause generated by phpMyAdmin.