# SQL LIKE returns all records

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run the following query in Phpmyadmin it returns 10 records, like it should

```
SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sku LIKE '142-401-117-282%'
```

But when I run the same query in my Php script, I get all the rows from the table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sku LIKE '142-401-117-282%' ";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row['sku']."<br>";
}
```

I'm selecting all the SKU's that start with  142-401-117-282, after come a `-` plus the size of the item

How do I get the 10 rows that I need?

Comment: That seems bizarre. Are you sure you're targetting the same database and table?

Comment: did you google for mysql limit? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and foreget phpmyadmin ... to change the results in phpmyadmin read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413288/phpmyadmin-change-default-number-of-rows-displayed

Comment: @scrowler yes, I am 100% sure. I performed queries on the same db and table before in the script

Comment: @donald123 irrelevant. If the manually performed query returns 10 records so should the PHP implementation. As an aside though, this question isn't going to be reproducible unless the OP can share a fiddle or example of this in practice.

Comment: You should use **[LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)** Clause.

Comment: @scrowler no .. phpmyadmin has a default_number_of_rows to display ;)

Comment: @scrowler how can I share a fiddle of something server related?

Comment: @donald123 yes, isn't it 30? 149514115 you can use something like [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @scrowler who knows? default it is imho 30 it can be 1000, **10**, 87 or what ever ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sku LIKE '142-401-117-282%' LIMIT 0,10";
```

where 0 is starting row position and 10 is its length.

Comment: It's not about limiting to ten, it's about the inconsistency.